# Write ruby code in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a Rails application where I try to write code into an string:

```
<% @diagnoses.each do |f| %>
  <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop#{f.id}" class=" tiny button dropdown expand">"#{f.beschreibung}"</a><br>
```

But somehow the `"drop#{f.id}"` and the `"#{f.beschreibung}"` are not written as a variable. 
What am I doing wrong and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `<%= %>`. However, I'd use the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper:

```
<% @diagnoses.each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to f.beschreibung, "#", data: {dropdown: "drop#{1}"}, class: "tiny button dropdown expand" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

you are most probably in an erb template so you have to do the following

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop<%= f.id %>" class="tiny button dropdown expand">
  <%= f.beschreibung %>
</a>
```

Comment: Edited out the double quotes. Don't think he wants them ;-)

Comment: @Mischa no worries. thanks! just wondering though. would making the file go through a ruby interpreter work as well? ie add a `.rb` extension? have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing this in a view, you need to use `<%= %>` and make sure the file has the `.erb` extension

you code should be

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop<%= f.id %>" class=" tiny button dropdown expand">"<%= f.beschreibung %>"</a><br>
```